# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on IF combined with OR statement

Tags: vba, excel

In my VBA code using excel I have

```
Dim Field2 As String

Field2 = Cells(i, 4).Value

If Right(Field2, 3) = ("A-1" Or "A-2" Or "B-1" Or "B-2" Or "C-1" Or "C-2" Or "D-1" Or "D-2" Or "D-3") Then
          Cells(i, 50).Value = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
End If
```

An when I run the code, I get the follow message:
"Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Do you have any idea how to make this code work?

Thank you

Fabio

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
If Right(Field2, 3) = "A-1" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "A-2" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "B-1" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "B-2" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "C-1" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "C-2" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "D-1" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "D-2" Or _
   Right(Field2, 3) = "D-3" Then
      Cells(i, 50).Value = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
End If
```

Or better still... this

```
Select Case Right(Field2, 3)
Case "A-1","A-2","B-1","B-2","C-1","C-2","D-1","D-2","D-3"
    Cells(i, 50).Value = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
End Select
```

**Note**: I am assuming that `i` is a valid row number

**Explanation**:

When comparing using an `If` statement, you cannot say `If A = B or C`. You are supposed to compare is separately. `If A = B or A = C Then`. Here each `OR` is its own `Boolean` statement i.e it will be evaluated separately.

When you have multiple such comparisons, it is better to use a Select Statement as shown in the example above.

Comment: Just to add to this: A statement like `If A = B Or C` would better be seen thought of as `If A = (B Or C)` where `(B Or C)` is the Bitwise Or (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) of expressions B and C. Of course, to carry out this bitwise or you must have two numbers, so the type mismatch error arises from doing `"String1" Or "String2"`, which is an invalid operation. Why VB uses the same keywords for both bitwise and logical operators is beyond me (and something I've been meaning to cover in the SO Docs...)

Comment: For sake of completeness, `If Field2 Like "*[A-D]-[1-2]" Or Field2 Like "*D-3" Then` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the alternatives:

You may use the Excel **OR** function as follows

```
Dim Str As String, ChkStr As Boolean
Field2 = Cells(i, 4)
Str = Right(Field2, 3)
ChkStr = WorksheetFunction.Or(Str = "A-1", Str = "A-2", Str = "B-1", Str = "B-2", Str = "C-1", _
                              Str = "C-2", Str = "D-1", Str = "D-2", Str = "D-3")

If ChkStr Then          'Alternatively: If ChkStr = True Then
    Cells(i, 50) = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
End If
```

or a slightly different approach from Siddharth Rout's answer using the benefit of the **Select Case** statement on text, especially for `"D-1"`, `"D-2"`, and `"D-3"`, to determine if the condition lies between other text in an alphabetical sense. **Caution:** this can at times cause unexpected results so make sure you test it beforehand.

```
Select Case Right(Field2, 3)
    Case "A-1" To "A-2", "B-1" To "B-2", "C-1" To "C-2", "D-1" To "D-3"
         Cells(i, 50) = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
End Select
```

The last but not the least is to use **For Each...Next** statement of an array

```
StrList = Array("A-1", "A-2", "B-1", "B-2", "C-1", "C-2", "D-1", "D-2", "D-3")

For Each element In StrList
    If Right(Field2, 3) = element Then
        Cells(i, 50) = "OtherPrtnrs /Dcrs & Dept heads"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

One point that should be made here is that, by default, VBA code is case sensitive.